# Sending multiple pmset repeat schedules to a Mac

Tags: command-line, unix, power

I'm sending `pmset repeat` to a bunch of Macs via Apple Remote Desktop and I don't know why only the last `pmset repeat` command is activated. Here's what I'm sending:

```
pmset repeat sleep MTWR 19:00:00
pmset repeat shutdown F 19:00:00
```

Here's what was activated on the Mac (10.6) (image)

[image: Power schedule]

Comment: In hindsight, I should have mentioned that I also tried the wakeorpoweron combined with sleep but it just catches the last command (e.g. sleep in this case)

Comment: Does it work locally?

Comment: Yes, it works..

Answer (score 1):

The solution is rather simple -- just put the command in one line like so:

```
pmset repeat wakeorpoweron MTWRF 6:30:00 sleep MTWRSU 16:00:00
```