# MacOS pmset — Schedule different wakeorpoweron per weekday

Tags: macos, scheduled-tasks

Related questions:

- [Sending multiple pmset repeat schedules to a Mac](https://superuser.com/questions/322863/sending-multiple-pmset-repeat-schedules-to-a-mac)
- [Pmset multiple repeating schedule pairs](https://superuser.com/questions/568114/pmset-multiple-repeating-schedule-pairs)

What I am trying to do

> pmset repeat wakeorpoweron MW 9:00:00 wakeorpoweron TRF 11:00:00

Basically, set up a different wake up schedule per day,

However when I check `pmset -g sched`, it turns out it doesnt set the power on accordingly, the last schedule overwrites the first one. I am not sure what I am doing incorrectly. It seems that the command can only have ONE schedule for poweron and another one for sleep.

Any ideas? It doesnt need to be through pmset, just to wake up at those times, or at a bare minimum, to ensure that launchctl is able to execute at those times is enough. (launchctl executed on first wake if a job was defined to start at a time before it)